# VB .NET Reading all lines in file

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io

I have a file with 3 lines:

```
    20220203A|47332580|4500|20220206|0245|||||||||||||||||||||
20220203B|47237607|4500|20220206|0243|||||||||||||||||||||
20220203C|47383542|4500|20220206|0241|||||||||||||||||||||
```

and im reading the file and just to test Im writing it to another file as i read the lines but it seems to be reading the last line only

here is the snippet:

```
     Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path)

        For Each fileName As String In fileEntries
            WriteToFile("fileName: " + fileName + vbNewLine)  ' read and process all files
            Dim lines() As String = File.ReadLines(fileName)
            For Each line As String In lines
                WriteToFile(line + vbNewLine)
            Next
        Next
```

the output is:

```
fileName: C:\temp\IM01.DAT
```

20220203A|47332580|4500|20220206|0245|||||||||||||||||||||

writetofile is:

```
    Public Sub WriteToFile(StrToWrite As String)
    Dim stream As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing
    Try
        stream = New IO.StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\MyFile.txt", True)
        stream.WriteLine(StrToWrite)
        stream.Flush() ' saves changes
        stream.Close() ' closes the file
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show what the contents of the written file look like after this method finishes? Also show what the WriteToFile method does.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `WriteToFile` actually replaces the content of the file with the single line. Note that you should be able to step through the code in a debugger, and see quite clearly that all the lines really are present.

Comment: `File.ReadLines` doesn't return an array, so this line is "wrong": `Dim lines() As String = File.ReadLines(fileName)`. I use quotes because it is presumably working but that would require `Option Strict Off` and for the system to implicitly convert the result to an array. You should ALWAYS work with `Option Strict On` unless you specifically require late binding, which will be rare. If you specifically want an array then call `ReadAllLines`. The whole point of `ReadLines` is that it provides access to one line at a time, reducing memory usage.

Comment: With regards to Jon's theory, it should be easy to check simply from the output file itself. You write a line containing the file name first and then the lines of the file. Is the file name in your output? If not then obviously you are overwriting that file as suggested. If you want to append to an existing file, make sure that you call a method that does that. Read the documentation for the class and method(s) you're using to see how that's done.

Comment: Public Sub WriteToFile(StrToWrite As String)
        Dim stream As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing
        Try
            stream = New IO.StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\MyFile.txt",
                True)
            stream.Write(StrToWrite)
            stream.Flush() ' saves changes
            stream.Close() ' closes the file
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

Comment: sorry its doing the 1st line:

Comment: fileName: C:\temp\IM01.DAT
20220203A|47332580|4500|20220206|0245|||||||||||||||||||||

Comment: Don't add comments to your own question, edit your question to post the additional content.

Comment: Put your streamwriter into a Using statement. Stop discarding errors with empty try catch blocks.

Comment: Thank you Andrew.  I got it,  i used streamreader and a while loop  and streamwriter